# Hough Transform Plane Detector 3DTK

Tags: c++, 3d, vtk, hough-transform

i am currently trying to use the Hough Transform Plane Detector of the 3DTK (http://slam6d.sourceforge.net/). When I try to compile it with the EXPORT_SHARED_LIBS option, i am getting linker errors in the cxspare_s project.

```
1>cs_convert.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 'cs_dl_spalloc' referenced in function 'cs_l_real'
1>cs_convert.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 'cs_ci_spalloc' referenced in function 'cs_i_complex'
1>cs_convert.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 'cs_cl_spalloc' referenced in function 'cs_l_complex'
```

The spalloc functions are defined in the cs.h header file in Path 3DTK\3rdparty\cxsparse-4.4.4\suitesparse, but they don't seem to be implemented. At least I can't find them anywhere.

Compiling the static libs works perfectly though.

I am running on Windows 7 with

- Visual Studio 2015 Professional
- 3DTK Revision 1179
- boost 1.60
- OpenCV 3.10
- zlib 1.2.8
- VTK 7.0

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Because I don't need the whole 3DTK, i also cloned just the Hough Transform Plane Detector (https://github.com/midas-journal/midas-journal-820). I removed the HoughPlanes.cpp, defined vtkHoughPlanes as Export class und compiled it to get the *.lib and *.dll file, which worked perfectly. Linking against the lib also works, but as soon as I include the vtkHoughPlanes Header, I get hundreds of times the same error:

```
Error C2666: "vtkOStreamWrapper::operator <<": 6 overloads have similar conversions C:\PROGRA~1\VTK\include\vtk-7.0\vtkTextProperty.h   44
```

So the compiler does not know which stream insertion operatoren << to use because of ambiguity. All errors lead to the same VTK macro "vtkGetVector3Macro" in several VTK headers. But the errors and the macro definition are all in the VTK itself, so what can I do about it? I can't typecast anywhere in my code to make the operator unambiguous, because I don't know the cause of the error in my code. There is no instance of vtkOStreamWrapper in the project itself.

Since the Hough Transform Plane Detector itself is an rather old project, is it possible, that VTK 7 is just not compatible anymore?

I would be grateful for any ideas.

Greets 
Dave

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue? I'm having the same problem while compiling 3DTK.

Comment: No sorry. Because I was running out of time I used the PCL RANSAC plane detection which worked perfectly for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A fork of the Github project you mention should be supported in later versions of VTK.

https://github.com/daviddoria/VTKHoughPlanes